# Function with no Return - How does this function work?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a old VB project and I'm rewriting it into C#.

I've got a few lines that do not fit on what I know about functions.  I've read MSDN and as far as I've understood it, a function must have a `Return` or an `Exit`, or if not (Does not makes sense having procedures) you can send the data `ByRef`.

This function does not have either of these, but still it's supposed to be doing something - if not I don't think the program would work, but it does.

Also it looks like it's calling itself but with an overload; but I don't know, it's too odd for me.

The function itself:

```
Private Function f(ByVal numero As Double) As String
    Dim intermedio As Double
    intermedio = numero * Factor 
    If intermedio - Int(intermedio) = 0 Then

        f = Format(intermedio, "0")
    Else
        f = Format(intermedio, "###0.0######")
    End If
    'f = Format(intermedio, "0.00000E+000")
    f = Replace(f, ",", ".")
    'f = Str(numero)
End Function
```

The variable factor is defined somewhere else in the code and it's:

```
double Factor = 1;
```

The calls to that function:

```
For Y = 0 To MaxY - 1
    X0 = X
    X1 = X + 1
    Y0 = Y
    Y1 = Y + 1
    Z00 = a(X0, Y0)
    Z01 = a(X0, Y1)
    Z10 = a(X1, Y0)
    Z11 = a(X1, Y1)
    Normal(X1 - X0, Y1 - Y0, Z11 - Z00, X1 - X0, 0, Z10 - Z00)

    objWriter.WriteLine("  facet normal " & f(i) & " " & f(j) & " " & f(k))
    objWriter.WriteLine("    outer loop")
    objWriter.WriteLine("      vertex " & f(X) & " " & f(Y) & " " & f(a(X, Y)))
    objWriter.WriteLine("      vertex " & f(X + 1) & " " & f(Y + 1) & " " & f(a(X + 1, Y + 1)))
    objWriter.WriteLine("      vertex " & f(X + 1) & " " & f(Y) & " " & f(a(X + 1, Y)))
    objWriter.WriteLine("    endloop")
    objWriter.WriteLine("  endfacet")

    Normal(0, Y1 - Y0, Z01 - Z00, X1 - X0, Y1 - Y0, Z11 - Z00)

    objWriter.WriteLine("  facet normal " & f(i) & " " & f(j) & " " & f(k))
    objWriter.WriteLine("    outer loop")
    objWriter.WriteLine("      vertex " & f(X) & " " & f(Y) & " " & f(a(X, Y)))
    objWriter.WriteLine("      vertex " & f(X) & " " & f(Y + 1) & " " & f(a(X, Y + 1)))
    objWriter.WriteLine("      vertex " & f(X + 1) & " " & f(Y + 1) & " " & f(a(X + 1, Y + 1)))
    objWriter.WriteLine("    endloop")
    objWriter.WriteLine("  endfacet")

Next Y
```

Comment: Setting the name of the function (f) with a value means the function returns that value. Old VB6 leftover I think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Visual Basic, the name of the function itself becomes a variable you can use within the function.  At the end of the function, whatever is left in it is used as the return value, unless an explicit `Return` statement is used.

In your case, `f` is used throughout.

Quoting [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx#code-snippet-3):

> The **Exit Function** and **Return** statements cause an immediate exit from a **Function** procedure. Any number of **Exit Function** and **Return** statements can appear anywhere in the procedure, and you can mix **Exit Function** and **Return** statements.
>
> If you use **Exit Function** without assigning a value to *name*, the procedure returns the default value for the data type that's specified in *returntype*. If *returntype* isn't specified, the procedure returns **Nothing**, which is the default value for **Object**.

Comment: Yeah thats just what i readed, but my little Knowledge of english lenguaje didnt noticed that on the first read, once i know the answer i can see it more clearly on MSDN

Answer (score 2):

```
f = Replace(f, ",", ".")
```

Name of your function is `f` and this local variable is your returned value (because name is the same). Is works automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In C#

```
    private string f(double numero)
{
    string functionReturnValue = null;
    double intermedio = 0;
    intermedio = numero * Factor;

    if (intermedio - Conversion.Int(intermedio) == 0) {
        functionReturnValue = Strings.Format(intermedio, "0");
    } else {
        functionReturnValue = Strings.Format(intermedio, "###0.0######");
    }
    //f = Format(intermedio, "0.00000E+000")
    functionReturnValue = Strings.Replace(f(), ",", ".");

    //f = Str(numero)
    return functionReturnValue;
}
```

As Steve and many others have mentioned in VB if the function and variable are named the same then the variable is returned... In C# add a functionReturnValue in place of f in the function and return it.